# Activity killed in background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to detect when activity is killed in background. I've succeeded to detect if it goes to background / foreground but not if its killed in background. I need to allow users to go background / foreground as many times as wants. Lets say fill some fields, go to another app, go back, fill more fields and so on... but if kill it from background, update / delete `Firebase Cloud Firestore` document.

1. I've already tried to override `onStop` / `onDestroy`. Function `onDestroy` works exactly what I want but only if its killed in background (button Home and then trash can or swipe) **immediately** (pressed Home button and Trash can in short time). But if I wait for a few seconds it wont do the same. It means : Depending on time spent in background, `Firebase Cloud Firestore` document sometimes doesn't update with certain data and sometimes does. Any explanation?
2. I've also tried `LifecycleObserver` and couldn't get the desired result.

Any help would be precious.
Thanks

Comment: *Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed... Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either on...* source official documentation

Comment: "I'm trying to detect when activity is killed in background" -- [activities are not "killed in background". Processes are.](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html) "I need to allow users to go background / foreground as many times as wants... but if kill it from background, update / delete Firebase Cloud Firestore document" -- that will be unreliable. Once your app's UI moves to the background, your process can be terminated at any point, and there is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called on any activity or service in your process.